# lftp 550 permission denied

Tags: ftp, debian, lftp

i've tried to create a script that will upload some file to a ftp server using lftp, but without any luck so far. If I used build in ftp command in debian I manage to succsessfully connected and put the file. 
Here is the debug output from lftp command:

```
lftp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx -e "put -O /out/ some_file_name" -d
---- using user `user01' and password from ~/.netrc
---- Resolving host address...
---- 1 address found:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx
---- Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx) port 21
<--- 220 (vsFTPd 2.0.7)                                         
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:                                                    
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  PASV
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  TVFS
<---  UTF8
<--- 211 End
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
<--- 200 Always in UTF8 mode.                                   
---> USER user01
<--- 331 Please specify the password.                           
---> PASS XXXX
<--- 230 Login successful.                                            
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/"                                                              
---> TYPE I
<--- 200 Switching to Binary mode.                                        
---> EPSV
<--- 550 Permission denied.                                               
---- Switching passive mode off
---- Closing data socket
---- Closing control socket
```

As you can see I'm using stored user name and password from .netrc file. I have another script that connect to the same server but uploads files and rename them inside the remote ftp folder using lftp again. Can someone help and explain why I cannot put with lfpt but can do it using ftp.

Comment: What happens if you just script the built-in debian command?

Comment: I'm using 'mv' command from lfpt, cause by specification must upload a file and when it is complete i must renaming it. For example - "put Xsome_file_name -O /some_remote_dir/ " and after that "cd /some_remote_dir/; mv Xsome_file_name some_file_name". Also I didnt find a way to upload a file using one line command that upload the file to some remote directory using only ftp.

Answer (score 3):

after add `set ftp:passive-mode true` and  `set ftp:prefer-epsv false` to /etc/lftp.conf the error is changed

```
<--- 230 Login successful.                                            
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/"                                                              
---> TYPE I
<--- 200 Switching to Binary mode.                                        
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,76,92)                      
---- Connecting data socket to (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 19548
---- Data connection established                                            
---> ALLO 710
<--- 550 Permission denied.                                               
---> STOR out/my_file_name
---> ABOR
put: Access failed: 550 Permission denied. (/out/my_file_name)
---- Closing aborted data socket
---- Closing control socket
```

Okay I've understand what ALLO means

> The ALLO command may be sent to a server that requires the necessary space for an uploaded to be reserved before the transfer takes place

so after a quick search in ftp man page, I've found a command to shut it down. After adding `set ftp:use-allo false` and with `epsv false` everything is fine now. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 3):

`lftp -e "set ftp:use-allo false; set ftp:passive-mode true; set ftp:prefer-epsv false; mirror -R {local dir} {remote dir}" -u {username},{password} {host}`

Use this single command to sync your file from local to server without 550 permission error.

Answer (score 1):

While `550 Permission denied.` is a strange response to the `EPSV` command it means that the server or some middlebox in between does not understand the `EPSV` command (likely a middlebox since the response to `FEAT` shows `EPSV` as supported). If you use the builtin `ftp` command instead of `lftp` it will probably use the older `PASV` command (IPv4 only) instead of the newer `EPSV` command (IPv4+IPv6 capable).

According to [the man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) there is a setting `ftp:prefer-epsv` which should default to `false`. Maybe some configuration is setting this value to true so that `lftp` will use `EPSV` instead of `PASV`. Check your settings (`set -a` inside lftp) and if it is true (expected) set it to `false` and try again, in the hope that it will then use `PASV` instead of `EPSV`.